# What's the preferred way of using Rails and Flex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache-flex, push

I'd like to create a service, similar to a chat application (realtime app).

From what I can see from my research, `BlazeDS` is the preferred way, but it involves Java and Java EE. Also, the latest Ruby results seem to be from 2009-2010, so they are likely outdated.

Are there any actively maintained Ruby/Rails solutions for integrating push notifications with Flex?

Comment: Flex is made to backend agnostic; so you can use whatever server side technology you want.  For RealTime solutions that include push technology; I believe Livecycle is the Adobe solution and GraniteDS is a free open source solution.  I believe that WebORB has a product for that too.  I don't know the Ruby world; but am unaware of a Ruby server/project w/ Push technology. If there is one; I have no doubt you can use it w/ Flex. I voted to close as StackOverflow is this is not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 7):

### The current situation

Do you *have* to use Flex? HTML5 [websockets](http://pusher.com/websockets) is a nascent but growing technology and there are implementations now. Flex's days are numbered. Yet, websockets doesn't yet have native support in IE.

- [em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket) is a ruby websocket server based on eventmachine. The service [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) is based on it.
- [Faye](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby) is a websocket server and client. ([Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye))
- There are other Ruby implementations such as [Cramp](http://cramp.in/) and [Socky](https://github.com/socky/socky-server-ruby).
- If you're open to servers in other technologies such as Node, there are many with Ruby or Javascript clients ready to go.

**Update**: I might mention that I looked into doing something similar with Flex a while back, and got a copy of [Flex on Rails](http://www.flexonrails.com/book.html). The book's [server push example](https://github.com/danielwanja/flexonrails/tree/master/20_Server_Push_with_Juggernaut) uses [Juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/), which unfortunately has [stopped further development](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/killing-a-library). The author states that [Server-Sent Events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) (SSEs) make Juggernaut redundant. All major browsers [except IE](http://caniuse.com/eventsource) support them natively, similar to the [situation with websockets](http://caniuse.com/websockets).

There are shims ("[polyfills](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/)") that use javascript to bring [these missing capabilities](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) to the browsers. For example, the [jQuery Graceful WebSocket](https://github.com/ffdead/jquery-graceful-websocket) is a jQuery plugin that implements a websocket client but falls back to AJAX polling so the functionality will still work in IE, just won't be quite as instant. Because it detects websocket support, as soon as a browser supports websockets they will be used.

### Bridging the Gap

We seem to be caught in a transition period, where we are at the sunset era of Flash but not yet at broad support for its replacement technologies. There is one library that may bridge the gap: [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/). This library selects the most capable technology transport at runtime. It will use Flash if present, but can also use websockets, AJAX long polling, AJAX multipart streaming, a "forever iframe" if necessary. This gives it broad browser support:

- IE 5.5+
- Safari 3+
- Google Chrome 4+
- Firefox 3+
- Opera 10.61+
- iPhone Safari
- iPad Safari
- Android Webkit
- WebOS Webkit

This is actually broader compatibility than either Flash/Flex or WebSockets alone. Socket.IO is implemented in Javascript for both server and client, so you need a server-side Javascript runtime such as Node.

### Possible solutions

While there don't seem to be many current references to a Rails 3 -> Flex solution (as you have found), it appears there is some traction with the combination of Ruby/Rails and Socket.IO.

If you want to add chat to a Rails app using Socket.IO, there's a nice reference blog post by Liam Kaufman who creates a chat app in Rails 3 using Socket.IO: http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2012/02/25/adding_real-time_to_rails_with_socket.IO_nodejs_and_backbonejs_with_demo/

There's also a [socket.io gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/socket.io) which adds support to the Cramp server mentioned above.

There also seem to be other stackoverflow questions with others working on the Rails 3 and Socket.IO combination.

### TL;DR summary

While there isn't much indication that folks are doing direct-to-Flex from Rails anymore, there are other solutions with the most promising being a combination of Rails and Socket.IO.

Comment: -1; because I don't believe this addreses the question of using Flex and Rails together.  The analogy I like to use is "If you asked me how to best make hamburgers and I told you to make hot dogs instead; you'd probably be upset, right?"

Comment: Sometimes I provide an alternate way to achieve the underlying goal, in this case to create a chat-like application. You have every right to downvote, although you obviously have a stake in Flex.

Comment: If you want to suggest alternate technologies; I suggest doing so in a comment on the main question; not as an answer which does not address the question.  In theory, the original poster could take any server side piece with push technology, such as the ones you recommended, and write a Flash-based client using the Flash Player socket support ( http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_5.html ).

Comment: Unfortunately, html 5 support is not great across all browsers. Flash support kind of is. That's the main reason behind it. I am aware of the Ruby websocket implementations ( we're using Faye in one of our projects ).

Comment: I've updated the post with more possibilities, specifically addressing the browser compatibility problem.

Comment: I think this answer is a lot better than the actual answer to his question, which is "no".

Comment: I agree with iioiooioo and disagree with Flextras -- you don't have a library for bridging every possible combo of technologies, especially in a technology stack which is indeed caught in a transition period. I would accept this answer.

Comment: Flex is irrelevant, actionscript3 is the focus. A socket solution is definatly a common and widely used solution to comms between server and client. A Socket solution also work for mobile. End to end i've had android/iphone->nodejs->flash all using socket libraries (notably http://socket.io/ for flash) +1 for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to live within the Ruby world, you can use regular [WebSockets](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket) to talk to a Flex application.  It won't be pretty, but it would work, and you could avoid the Java back-end.  This would be a lot more raw than telling BlazeDS to fling structures around, but it should be doable.

On the Flex client side, there is a library written by [Kaazing](http://kaazing.com/download.html), that is bundled with their WebSocket servers.  Download one of their WebSocket servers, and in the client-libs folder, there should be a swc (with docs) that you can use to talk to em-websocket (or really, any websocket tech).

Now, all this being said, you won't have nearly the scaleability of BlazeDS or GraniteDS, but it should work for smaller implementations and demos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/rubyamf/rubyamf or https://github.com/victorcoder/rubyamf_plugin

But you will be have problem with realtime messaging because rubyamf and rubyamf_plugin don't support RTMP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RestfulX](http://restfulx.github.com/) gem & Flex framework.  That's what I use for Rails/Flex.